# Why does setting an image's src to a gif already present on the page reset the gif animation for the images already present?

Tags: javascript, html, animated-gif

I am coding a webpage on which many GIFs appear, forming a grid. All of these images on the webpage can actually take only two different sources: `0.gif` and `1.gif`, and when clicked, a GIF should switch source - if the src was `0.gif`, switch to `1.gif` and vice versa.

So far I've done something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img0" src="0.gif">
    <img id="img1" src="1.gif">
    <img id="changing_img" src="0.gif">
</body>
<script>
    changing_img = document.getElementById("changing_img")
    changing_img.onclick = changeImg
    changing_img.currentState = 0

    function changeImg(event) {
        img = event.target
        newState = 1 - img.currentState
        img.currentState = newState
        img.src = `${newState}.gif`
    }
</script>
```

It works fine, *but* I've noticed that when I click `changing_img`, there is an undesired side effect: the other GIF on the page that already had `changing_img`'s new source is reset at the beginning of its animation. This shows up in both Chrome and Firefox.

Example: when I first load the page, `changing_img`'s source is `0.gif`. When I click it, its source changes to `1.gif` *and* `img1` has its GIF animation reset to the beginning.

Why does that happen? How could I prevent it? I figured this would have to do with the way the images are loaded in the browser, but I don't know what to search.

Comment: That’s kind of surprising. Probably not a good behaviour for browsers. Is rendering them manually with a canvas an option? I’m not sure how it compares for efficiency, but it’ll at least work consistently and won’t be complicated.

Comment: I did not know about canvas, thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try and write an update

Comment: @Ry- it worked fine with a canvas, thanks for the tip! Though I'm curious of what caused the initial issue